# How to control frame size with Tkinter and Python2.7?

Tags: python, tkinter, size, frame

I would like to have bigger frame size by default, but this code doesn't work like that. What am I doing wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master, width=600, height=450)
        frame.grid()
        frame.pack_propagate(0)  # tell frame not to let its children control its size

        self.label_file = Label(frame, text="Enter CSV file:")
        self.label_encode = Label(frame, text="Enter encoding:")
        self.entry_file = Entry(frame)
        self.entry_encode = Entry(frame)

        self.label_file.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_encode.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_file.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_encode.grid(row=1, column=1)

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Top list")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `pack_propagate` but then using `grid` to actually lay out the widgets. If you're using `grid`, you must call `grid_propagate`.

I urge  you to resist the temptation to do this. Tkinter programs behave much better with geometry propagation turned on. If you're trying to solve some particular layout problem, there are probably better ways to solve that than to turn propagation off.

I've used tkinter for more than a couple of decades, and the times I've needed to turn geometry propagation off I can probably count on one hand, with fingers left over.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'm beginner with Python and GUI and I'm learning this on a hard way, trying to write a GUI app for some of my Python scripts. It's not that important, I was just curious why doesn't it resize itself.